# How to launch an Amazon EC2 in a particular VPC in YAML CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

How can I launch an Amazon EC2 instance in a particular subnet of a VPC using a YAML template in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes access this in the future, I was able to solve this by specifying the following: AvailabilityZone, SecurityGroupIds (not SecurityGroups), and SubnetId.

```
Resources:
    EC2Instance: 
        Properties:
          AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
          ImageId: ami-Id
          InstanceType: 
            Ref: InstanceType
          KeyName: 
            Ref: KeyName
          Tags:
              -
                Key: "Name"
                Value:
                  Ref: InstanceName
          SecurityGroupIds:
              - sg-idHere
          SubnetId: subnet-idHere
        Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
```

Make sure that the security group is available to the VPC you are trying to use. The SubnetId should represent the VPC.

Hierarchy:
VPC->SubnetID->SecurityGroupId

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CF template for create a ec2 instance in region singapore. I have just used this template. If you are running in the other region please change ImageId name to met with you region

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'VPC with private subnets in two availability zones'
Parameters:
  PrivateSubnet:
    Description: Private Subnet to Attach NAT Gateway.
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues: [t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium, t2.large, m3.medium, m3.large,
      m3.xlarge, m3.2xlarge, m4.large, m4.xlarge, m4.2xlarge, m4.4xlarge, m4.10xlarge,
      c4.large, c4.xlarge, c4.2xlarge, c4.4xlarge, c4.8xlarge, c3.large, c3.xlarge,
      c3.2xlarge, c3.4xlarge, c3.8xlarge, r3.large, r3.xlarge, r3.2xlarge, r3.4xlarge,
      r3.8xlarge, i2.xlarge, i2.2xlarge, i2.4xlarge, i2.8xlarge]
    ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid instance type.

  SSHKeyName:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid KeyName

  VolumeSize:
    Description: size of volume
    Type: Number
    Default: 20
    ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid Number
    AllowedValues: [20, 30, 40, 50]

  IOPS:
    Description: total ipos
    Type: Number
    Default: 100
    ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid Number
    AllowedValues: [100, 200, 500, 1000]

  ImageId:
    Type: String
    Description: 'value for region singapore. If you using other version please choose right'
    Default: 'ami-33e4bc49'


Resources:
  EC2Example:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref SSHKeyName
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        -
          DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: io1
            Iops: !Ref IOPS
            DeleteOnTermination: false
            VolumeSize: !Ref VolumeSize

Outputs:
  EC2Example:
    Description: 'Ec2 instance EC2Example'
    Value: !Ref EC2Example
    Export:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-EC2Example'
```

Comment: I can tell this was copied/'collaborated' from the description. "VPC: public and private subnets in two availability zones, a cloudonaut.io template"
It's probably the best answer here.
Just wanted to say that there are Parameter types that you can put instead of Strings now.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types

Comment: ok. I will update the description for making sense. Thank you for your comment @mutant_city

Answer (score 0):

The CloudFormation template includes a `SubnetId` parameter:

```
Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
Properties: 
  SubnetId: String
```

Simply insert the ID of the existing Subnet (eg `subnet-1234abcd`).

Comment: Hi John, Thank You,
But its not working, 
I've tried this before, and still my instances are launching in my default VPC.

Comment: Did you specify a `NetworkInterfaces`? If so, this overrides `SubnetId`.